# How does a C# program execute a script file on a remote computer?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-remoting

I am executing a powershell script on a remote computer through C#. 
I am passing it in the following way through a C# program :

```
String file = "C:\\scriptfile.ps1";
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
pipeline.Commands.AddScript(file);
Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
```

How is the script getting executed remotedly. Is the script file copied to the remote machine. Or is the commands in the script file passed and executed line by line?

Comment: I have read about this before, and the answer was "sending the commands". I will start looking for that discussion and post it here when I find it.